# Group Data in R by n number of rows

Tags: r

I have a small dataset from a survey. There are 18 combinations of attributes for TVs, and 15 people rated each combination from 1-9.

I have the data in the following columns in a csv (with the values in parenthesis each in a different row):

Combinations (1,2, 3,...,18), Panel_LCD (0,1,1,...,0), Panel_OLED(1,0,0,...,0), Panel_QLED(0,0,0,...,1), Res_HD(1,0,1,...,0), Res_4K(0,1,1,...,1), and same for 3 different sizes and 3 different price points. Lastly, one more column for the 1-9 rating each person gave each combination.

Part of my assignment is to show the relative importance of each attribute for each person's set of answers.

I'm going crazy trying to figure out how to do some kind of a "for" statement for this.

My alternative is to copy/paste the code they gave me 15 times (too much to even copy here!)

```
dput(tv_data)
```

output:
structure(list(Perfil = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L,
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L,
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L,
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L,
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L,
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L,
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 1L,
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L,
16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L,
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L,
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 2L,
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L,
17L, 18L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L,
13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L,
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 2L, 3L,
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L,
18L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L,
14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L,
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L,
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L
), panel_lcd = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L,
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L,
0L, 0L, 1L), panel_oled = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L,
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L,
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L,
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L,
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L,
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L,
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L,
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L,
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), panel_qled = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L,
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L,
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L,
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), res_hd = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), res_4k = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), tam_42 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L,
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L,
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L,
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L,
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L,
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L,
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L,
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L,
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L,
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L,
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L,
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L,
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L,
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L,
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L,
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L,
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L,
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), tam_55 = c(0L, 1L, 0L,
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L,
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L,
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L,
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L,
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L,
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L,
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L,
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L,
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L,
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L,
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L,
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L,
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L,
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L,
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L,
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L,
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), tam_65 = c(1L, 0L,
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L,
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L,
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L,
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L,
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L,
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L,
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L,
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L,
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L,
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L,
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L,
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L,
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L,
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L,
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L,
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L,
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), p_500 = c(0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), p_1000 = c(0L,
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), p_1500 = c(1L,
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), preferencias = c(8L,
7L, 7L, 9L, 6L, 5L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 7L, 3L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 7L,
5L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 7L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L,
4L, 3L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 3L, 1L, 9L, 4L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 2L,
2L, 9L, 4L, 2L, 9L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 8L,
7L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 7L,
5L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 5L, 3L, 9L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 8L, 8L,
3L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 4L,
9L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 8L,
3L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L,
5L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 5L, 3L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 2L,
8L, 6L, 3L, 8L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 8L,
7L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L,
4L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 2L, 9L, 9L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 1L,
7L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L,
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-270L))

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It's easier to help you if you make your question reproducible by including data in a useable format eg paste the output of `dput(your_data)` into the question to enable testing and verification of possible solutions, or if you have a very large dataset `dput(head(your_data, n))` where n is an integer large enough to include a meaningful extract of the dataset. Also include an indication of the expected output. [link for guidance on asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks @Peter, I've added the output of dput(tv_data). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to look at the mean rating for each combination:

```
ratings <- tapply(tv_data$preferencias, tv_data$Perfil, mean)
print(ratings, digits=4)
#     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18 
# 5.533 3.933 4.800 7.667 6.333 4.667 6.733 6.933 6.467 4.533 3.600 2.733 5.467 3.800 3.467 6.467 5.533 4.133 
print(sort(ratings, decreasing=TRUE), digits=4)
#     4     8     7     9    16     5     1    17    13     3     6    10    18     2    14    11    15    12 
# 7.667 6.933 6.733 6.467 6.467 6.333 5.533 5.533 5.467 4.800 4.667 4.533 4.133 3.933 3.800 3.600 3.467 2.733
```

So combination 4 is the top rated and combination 12 is the lowest rated. If you want to add more descriptive information:

```
attribs <- colnames(tv_data)[2:12]
present <- as.matrix(tv_data[1:18, 2:12]) > 0
labels <- t(apply(x, 1, function(x) attribs[x]))
results <- data.frame(Comb=1:18, ratings, labels)
results
#    Comb  ratings         X1     X2     X3     X4
# 1     1 5.533333  panel_lcd res_4k tam_65 p_1500
# 2     2 3.933333  panel_lcd res_4k tam_55 p_1500
# 3     3 4.800000 panel_oled res_4k tam_42 p_1500
# 4     4 7.666667 panel_oled res_4k tam_65 p_1000
# 5     5 6.333333 panel_qled res_4k tam_55 p_1000
# 6     6 4.666667 panel_oled res_4k tam_42 p_1000
# 7     7 6.733333  panel_lcd res_4k tam_65  p_500
# 8     8 6.933333 panel_oled res_4k tam_55  p_500
# 9     9 6.466667 panel_qled res_4k tam_42  p_500
# 10   10 4.533333 panel_oled res_hd tam_65 p_1500
# 11   11 3.600000 panel_qled res_hd tam_55 p_1500
# 12   12 2.733333 panel_qled res_hd tam_42 p_1500
# 13   13 5.466667 panel_qled res_hd tam_65 p_1000
# 14   14 3.800000  panel_lcd res_hd tam_55 p_1000
# 15   15 3.466667  panel_lcd res_hd tam_42 p_1000
# 16   16 6.466667 panel_qled res_hd tam_65  p_500
# 17   17 5.533333 panel_oled res_hd tam_55  p_500
# 18   18 4.133333  panel_lcd res_hd tam_42  p_500
```